# Using Redis bitmap operations like BITCOUNT from .NET?

Tags: .net, redis

The Redis bitmap operations like [SETBIT](http://redis.io/commands/setbit), [GETBIT](http://redis.io/commands/getbit), [BITCOUNT](http://redis.io/commands/bitcount) and [BITOP](http://redis.io/commands/bitop) look interesting for certain scenarios, like analytics. But are these accessible from any of the available .NET Redis drivers, like [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis)?

I've been browsing the source code of ServiceStack.Redis and that seems to offer a support for SETBIT and GETBIT, but I'm not seeing any mentions of BITCOUNT or BITOP.

So, is there any .NET Redis drivers out there which allow me to use operations like BITOP? If not, can I use any of the drivers to send "raw" commands to Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booksleeve has support, you can browse some of the code here:

https://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/source/browse/BookSleeve/IStringCommands.cs?r=cbbead9c7c2b2e489b5211b3f79a717d974270b7

https://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/source/browse/Tests/Strings.cs?r=ac3029560bd19dd4b505e521187ddbe98e7ffa16